# Arduino and NodeMCU problem with wifi conecction

Tags: wifi, nodemcu, loop

Hello guys I am beginner with micro controllers but I am trying to make a simple IoT with Arduino and NodeMCU as WiFi. I was using this tutorial and code https://www.electronicshub.org/wifi-controlled-led-using-esp8266-and-arduino/.

When I upload the code for the first time everything worked perfectly but every other time when I upload the same code my program is stuck in a loop.

Program is in infinite while loop `while(!esp8266.find("OK"))` because as far as i understand it didnt receive the OK status from ESP.

But in fact `esp8266Serial("AT+CWJAP=\"SSID\",\"Password\"\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);` prints OK in my console so it means that it should work but it doesnt...

Do you guys have any idea whats the reason?

Code looks as follows;

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); //Pin 2 & 3 of Arduino as RX and TX. Connect TX and RX of ESP8266 respectively.
#define DEBUG true
#define led_pin 11 //LED is connected to Pin 11 of Arduino


void setup()
  {
    pinMode(led_pin, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
    Serial.begin(9600);
    esp8266.begin(115200); //Baud rate for communicating with ESP8266. Your's might be different.
    esp8266Serial("AT+RST\r\n", 5000, DEBUG); // Reset the ESP8266
    esp8266Serial("AT+CWMODE=1\r\n", 5000, DEBUG); //Set station mode Operation
    esp8266Serial("AT+CWJAP=\"SSID\",\"Password\"\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);//Enter your WiFi network's SSID and Password.

    while(!esp8266.find("OK"))
    {
      }
    esp8266Serial("AT+CIFSR\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);//You will get the IP Address of the ESP8266 from this command.
    esp8266Serial("AT+CIPMUX=1\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
    esp8266Serial("AT+CIPSERVER=1,80\r\n", 5000, DEBUG);
  }

void loop()
  {
    if (esp8266.available())
      {
        if (esp8266.find("+IPD,"))
          {
            String msg;
            esp8266.find("?");
            msg = esp8266.readStringUntil(' ');
            String command1 = msg.substring(0, 3);
            String command2 = msg.substring(4);

            if (DEBUG)
              {
                Serial.println(command1);//Must print "led"
                Serial.println(command2);//Must print "ON" or "OFF"
              }
            delay(100);

              if (command2 == "ON")
                    {
                      digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
                    }
                   else
                     {
                       digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
                     }
          }
      }
  }

String esp8266Serial(String command, const int timeout, boolean debug)
  {
    String response = "";
    esp8266.print(command);
    long int time = millis();
    while ( (time + timeout) > millis())
      {
        while (esp8266.available())
          {
            char c = esp8266.read();
            response += c;
          }
      }
    if (debug)
      {
        Serial.print(response);
      }
    return response;
  }
```

Comment: use the WiFiEsp library

Comment: why do you need to upload the same code more than once?

Comment: @Juraj thanks for your answer, I will read about it.

Comment: @jsotola thanks for your answer, well i made some changes to my code and uploaded it but it stuck in infinite loop so i revert changes and upload original code which worked before but now it is also stuck in the same loop. It never finds "OK".

Comment: Your `esp8266Serial` function already read the response including the "OK" from the input so find() can't read it again